# How to shorten the plotting code using slots and table?

Tags: plotting, functional-style, table, slot

**Background Information**

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
f[z_, zh_, B_] := 1 - z^4/zh^4 + 2/3 B^2 z^4 Log[z]

Temp[zh_, B_] := -(D[f[z, zh, B], z]/(4 \[Pi])) /. z -> zh

T = 0.195; \[Epsilon] = 10^-6;
```

Now I calculate the various zh values at different B values using this method:

```
{zhB0, zhB0pt25, zhB0pt5, zhB0pt75, zhB1} = 
 SolveValues[Temp[zhsol, #] == T, zhsol, Reals][[1]] & /@ {0, 0.25, 
   0.5, 0.75, 1}
```

**Main Question**

How can I plot the graphs of $f$ v/s $z$ where I take the `B` values from 0 to 1 and `zh` values from `zhB0` to `zhB1` respectively without making repetitive code lines and then combining using the `Show` command?

**Note**: The range of z also changes, it goes from `0` to `zhsol` value calculated at corresponding `B` value.

**Some techniques that I used and related secondary questions**

1. *Slotting method*

I used this code to vary the `B` values but don't have an idea how to vary the `zh` values simultaneously:

```
Plot[f[z, zhB0, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.25], {z, \[Epsilon], zhB0}]
```

[image: varying the B]

Is there a way to change the colours as well for different `B` values in the above plot using the same approach?

2. *Tabular method*

I used the code below to vary both `B` and `zh` values but I was not sure how to effectively use the `zh` values in the right way and hence the weird plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[f[z, zh, B], {zh, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5}, {B, 0, 1, 
    0.25}]], {z, \[Epsilon], 5}]
```

[image: zh and B vary]

How can I vary `B` and `zh` values simultaneously in the above plot and also in the right order, keeping in mind the `z` range?

Comment: I think what you want is a flattened version of the Table output: `Evaluate[
 Table[f[z, zh, B], {zh, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5}, {B, 0, 1, 0.25}] ~ Flatten ~ 1]` within your `Plot`. I would really rather move the calculation outside Plot, assign it to a variable, and then use that variable inside Plot for clarity though. That will also avoid the need for Evaluate.

Comment: I just noticed that you mention that: "The range of z also changes". I think that alone makes it much easier to generate individual plots and then combine them with Show. You can only have one independent variable specification in `Plot`; you would have to enclose each function in some form of If or Piecewise statement to restrict their plotting to a smaller range within Plot. That seems like a lot of work.

Comment: More in general, perhaps you could describe what you are trying to achieve more in general. This is starting to approach an XY problem. Shortening the plotting code alone does not seem a worthwhile goal: readability and maintainability will both suffer.

Comment: @MarcoB I understand that and already have a solution with `Show`. The reason I asked this question was basically to learn other methods available since this is just a tiny fraction (prototype) of my big code. Also `zh` doesn't have the value `{zh, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5}` in reality, I used them just for trial. The real values are `{zhB0, zhB0pt25, zhB0pt5, zhB0pt75, zhB1}`. I hope I explained my point clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_, zh_, B_] := 1 - z^4/zh^4 + 2/3  B^2  z^4  Log[z]

Temp[zh_, B_] = -(D[f[z, zh, B], z]/(4  π)) /. z -> zh // Simplify;

T = 195/1000; ϵ = 10^-6;

zhB[B_?NumericQ] := zhB[B] =
  SolveValues[Temp[zhsol, B] == T, zhsol, Reals][[1]]
```

**EDIT:** The legend in my original answer was mislabeled. Using `Tooltip` to verify the legend:

```
Legended[
 Show[
  Plot[Tooltip[f[z, zhB[#], #], #], {z, 0, zhB[#]},
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][4  # + 1],
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {z, f})] & /@
   Range[0, 1, 1/4],
  PlotRange -> All,
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], {0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1},
   LegendLabel -> Style[B, 14]], {0.25, 0.45}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** You can avoid using `Show` with [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Tooltip[
     ConditionalExpression[f[z, zhB[#], #], z <= zhB[#]],
     #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/4]],
 {z, 0, zhB[0]},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {z, f}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1},
    LegendLabel -> Style[B, 14]], {0.25, 0.45}],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for letting me know these important tools.